# how to set the title for a link in html

Tags: html

I want to set new title for a link in html

Normal way to set title i simply insert the title inside `<a>` tag.

But i want to hide the title that is inside the `<a>` tag. and set a new title for link. I do not want to modify `innerHTML` the `<a>` tag. But i just want to put an attribute which will hide the current `innerHTML` and put its attribute name instead.

my purpose :

i want to implement in place editing for url. if user hover over the link he gets another link EDIT associated with the current link. if user click on link he redirects to the link. and if user click on EDIT link the the in place editing for the url enabled using bootstrap editable library. Bootstrap lib demands that whatever inside the `<a>` tag (correct me if i am wrong) will be taken value of the field to be edited. So i dont want to modify `innerHTML` of `<a>` tag.

I am currently using title attribute for the same, But it is making no sense for my purpose.
Is there any attribute available, to achieve my objective?

Comment: What *is* your purpose?

Comment: please go through my edited part. (my purpose)

Comment: Don't try to hack around the way the script works, just edit the script so it takes its data from somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no HTML attribute that will override the child nodes of an `<a>` element and render different content there.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with javascript:

```
 window.open(link, "Your Website Title");
```

Comment: This will open a new window and name it "Your Website Title". It won't change the text displayed in the link. The name of the window *will never be displayed to the user*. The code will fail in older versions of Internet Explorer (as they do not allow spaces in window names).